# How to find prisma records where child record satisfies x and children count is greater than 0?

Tags: orm, prisma, prisma2

I have two prisma models product and productVariation.The product model is

```
model Product {
 id String
 name String
 variants ProductVariant[] @relation()
 ...
}
```

and the product variation model is

```
model ProductVariant {
 id String
 stock Int
 price Float
 product Product @relation(fields:[productId],references:[id])
 productId String
 ....
}
```

How can i find all products in a given price range between x and y while also performing pagination using prisma take and skip

My approach to solving this was to find all products where it has atleast a variant that matches the price range and include variants where price is between the given range.

```
const products = await prisma.product.findMany({
  where:{
    variants:{
       some: {
          AND: [{price:{gte: x}},{price:{lte:y}}] 
        }
      }
   },
  {include:{variants:{where:{AND: [{price:{gte: x}},{price:{lte:y}}] }}}}
})
```

My expectation was by filtering by some I'll only get products with variants which satisfies the price range however I'm getting all products in the products table even those with variants that dont satisfly the price range i.e list of variants is empty